# IndexOutOfBoundsException not being thrown JFrame

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I have code which increments a index in an `arraylist.get(index)`, this is used as a next button when I reach the end of the list it's suppose to throw an `IndexOutOFBoundsException` and display a message in a textbox. The issue is if I keep incremementing the exception is never caught and it keeps restarting the `arraylist`, like it goes to the end and then restarts from beginning.

The search index iniatialized to 0 outside of the button handler

```
  try{
    setResidentialFields(results,searchindex);

      }
      catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
          jTextField17.setText("NO MORE PROPERTIES");
      }
       searchindex++; //increment for next element in current search
```

This is a line from the `setResidentialFields` method

```
  jTextField17.setText(String.valueOf(r.get(index).getTax())); //tax
```

---

To reply to first answer this is how I changed my code

```
searchindex++;


    try{


  jButton1.doClick();
  }
  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
      jTextField7.setText("No more properties to display");
  }
```

still doesn't work

Comment: I'd like to add that when I manually enter an out of range value in the line  setResidentialFields(results,3343); the program crashes with the exception however not when I'm incremementing the variable on buttonclick

Comment: Are you sure you're catching the right exception? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int- says `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Are you sure `setResidentialFields` is throwing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException when I replace 'searchindex' with 333 for example, but not when the searchindex variable is incrememented out of range In the example I tried arrayindexoutofbounds just for debugging

Comment: I Tried IndexOutOfBoundsException aswell. Doesn't work it just keeps restarting the arraylist showing elements from 0 after it reaches end

Comment: So, you actually artificially fire an event to button? Instead of that you can consider another approach to the problem. **What** should I do when the action is performed on `jButton1`?

Comment: I'm trying to help you. What is the code inside `jButton1.doClick()`? I mean what is the implementation of action performed on `jButton1`?

Comment: s.get(0), s.get(indexsize), this is the problem , the first piece of code is the button1. , I am trying to increment using a next button which fetches next item in arraylist however when it gets to end it just restarts DOESNT THROW INDEXOUTOFBOUNDS OR CATCHES IT

Comment: Sorry, I did what I could. I assume putting your entire code here isn't appropriate (you'll get plenty of down votes). I suggest you to debug your code, put the breaking points when your `indexToSearch` is changed... See what happens. Good luck, firend

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your `indexToSearch` isn't incremented in the right place, **or** you *never* break the loop (either the property is found or not). Here is an example how to do it:

```
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int indexToSearch = 0;
        int propertyToFind = 7;

        while (true) {
            try {

                if (arr[indexToSearch] == propertyToFind) {
                    System.out.println("found at index " + indexToSearch);
                    break;
                }

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("property " + propertyToFind + " not found");
                break;
            }

            indexToSearch++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: edited my code, I incremement before the try so I assume it would still be valid

Comment: I don't think so - you should increment the index **after** the current search. Please, notice the code I've written is just an simplified example. Try to understand the logic **when** your button is pressed (or clicked)